# Identifying the version on windows via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I was trying to run a powershell script based on the version of windows i use. I referred few documents and wrote this code on my own. I am not able to execute the batch file. The output flashes for a second or so and then it closes.I tried to call the batch file from command prompt and i got an error which said

```
( was unexpected at this time.
```

I have attached the code below. Please to help!

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=4-7 delims=[.] " %%i in ("ver") do @ ( if %%i==Version (set myvar=%%i.%%k ) else ( set myvar=%%i.%%j))

IF %myvar%==10.0 ( goto power ) ELSE (goto cont)

:power
powershell.exe -file C:\Users\Kashy\Desktop\secure.ps1
set var=%errorlevel%
IF %var%==5 ( echo "Disable Secure boot mode. Refer our readme document for more details." ) ELSE (goto cont) 

goto eof

:cont
echo hello

:eof
pause
exit
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're writing a batch file that calls Powershell. Why not just write it all in Powershell?

Comment: wrong quotes: `...  %%i in ('ver') do ...`. Doublequotes forces `for` to take the string literally, so `myvar` is left empty, which leads to a syntax error with the `if`.

Comment: @HongOoi I am writing a batch file to install certain softwares. So i can't use powershell

Comment: @Stephan Lemme try that..thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Because the intention is not to identify the Windows version but to detect if the version is Windows 10, I would use `WMIC`.

This should identify only those systems running Windows 10 or newer:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OV="
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'WMIC OS Where "Version<'4'" Get Version 2^>Nul') Do For %%B In (%%A
) Do Set "OV=%%A"
If Defined OV GoTo Start
Echo=
Echo Your Windows version does not meet the requirements
Echo Press any key to exit . . .
Echo=
Pause>Nul
Exit /B

:Start
Rem your code for Win10+
```

I used `<` with `4` to `GoTo Start` only on Windows 10+, *(a string comparison will find that the first character, `1` is less than `4`)*